# why does variable's address change in python when the variable is assigned a different value?

Tags: python

I am using `repl.it` for python3 -
Here is a sequence of assignments I did

```
  x34=20
   x34
=> 20
   hex(id(x34))
=> '0x7fdb5d318960'
   x34=30
   hex(id(x34))
=> '0x7fdb5d318aa0'
   hex(id(x34))
=> '0x7fdb5d318aa0'
   x34
=> 30
   hex(id(x34))
=> '0x7fdb5d318aa0'
   x34=20
   hex(id(x34))
=> '0x7fdb5d318960'
```

why does the address of the variable `x34` change when I reassign it value `30`?

Comment: You were never looking at the address of the variable in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

The fundamental misunderstanding you have is that *id's belong to Python objects*, not the variables. So, *any* reassignment to a new object, would cause the id's to change:

```
>>> x = (1,2)
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107526e48'
>>> x = (2, 4)
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107526e88'
```

Note, every time you create a new object, this happens:

```
>>> x = (1, 2)
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107526e48'
>>> x = (1, 2)
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107526d48'
>>> x = (1, 2)
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107526dc8'
```

Immutability or lack thereof has nothing to do with it. Note, `tuple` objects are immutable. However, there is a CPython implementation detail that [small `int`s are cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers). This is why you'll see the following behavior:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x10714d920'
>>> x = 10
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x10714d920'
>>> x = 10
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x10714d920'
```

Essentially, in CPython, `int` objects between -5 and 256 are singletons. Just like `None`:

```
>>> x = None
>>> id(x)
4413491112
>>> x = None
>>> id(x)
4413491112
```

However, this wont work the same way with large `int`s, and works just like it does with `tuple`s:

```
>>> x = 888
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107550070'
>>> x = 888
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x10736aef0'
>>> x = 888
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107550030'
```

Be careful, though, since `id` is only guaranteed unique for *the lifetime* of the object. So, sometimes, you'll see the same memory being returned from the heap, since the Python interpreter tries to be efficient with memory:

```
>>> x = 888
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107550050'
>>> x = 888
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x10736aef0'
>>> x = 888
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107550090'
>>> x = 888
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x10736aef0'
>>> x = 888
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107550070'
```

Again, this might happen with *any* object:

```
>>> x = object()
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x1072db120'
>>> x = object()
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x1072db110'
>>> x = object()
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x1072db120'
```

And the value of the object doesn't matter,

```
>>> x = 888
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107549fd0'
>>> x = 999
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107550090'
>>> x = 777
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x107549fd0'
```

Indeed, neither does the *type* necessarily matter either:

```
>>> class A:
...    pass
...
>>> class B:
...    pass
...
>>> class C:
...    pass
...
>>> for i in range(12):
...     if i%3 == 1:
...         print(A())
...     elif i%3 == 2:
...         print(B())
...     else:
...         print(C())
...
<__main__.C object at 0x107535a58>
<__main__.A object at 0x107535a58>
<__main__.B object at 0x107535a58>
<__main__.C object at 0x107535a58>
<__main__.A object at 0x107535a58>
<__main__.B object at 0x107535a58>
<__main__.C object at 0x107535a58>
<__main__.A object at 0x107535a58>
<__main__.B object at 0x107535a58>
<__main__.C object at 0x107535a58>
<__main__.A object at 0x107535a58>
<__main__.B object at 0x107535a58>
```

This is all at the discretion of the interpreter implementation.

However, if you keep another reference to an object, the original will not die during reassignment, and that *is* guaranteed:

```
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x1072db140'
>>> y = x
>>> hex(id(y)) # guaranteed to be the same as x
'0x1072db140'
>>> x = object()
>>> hex(id(x)) # guaranteed to be new
'0x1072db130'
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillage, can you please tell me the reason behind numbers -5 and 256 ? Is there anything special in it ?

Comment: @ankit they are just the range of numbers chosen for the small int cache based on how common they are

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillage

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you are doing with each assignment is creating a new object of type `int`, de-referencing the older one (`20 in this case`), and referencing with the variable (`x34`) to the new one (`30`).

Still be careful, because implementations could be tricky, look this:

```
>>> x34=20
>>> x34
20
>>> hex(id(x34))
'0x107d67f70'
>>> x34=30
>>> x34
30
>>> hex(id(x34))
'0x107d680b0'
>>> x35=30
>>> hex(id(x35))
'0x107d680b0'
```

As you can see, two different variables (`x34` and `x35`) are pointing to the same object ( `30` in this case) when they "theoretically" shouldn't 
because the two `30` are different objects even they have the same values.

The Python interpreter is smart enough to realize that `30` is an immutable object, so it avoids wasting memory creating two `30` when with just one is enough because it (the interpreter) will never modify (due to the immutability rules) one object and such modification reflected in the other variable that point to the same object.

Comment: Nice explanation! To complement:
`>>> a=30
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x7fcba6c0b4f0'
>>> hex(id(30))
'0x7fcba6c0b4f0'
` **:-)**

Comment: No. This *is not generalizable to all immutable objects*. This is an implementation detail for CPYthon, which caches small ints as an optimization.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Never said *is generalizable to all immutable objects*, I even said *Still be careful, because implementations could be tricky*. Pls, help me to improve my answer if was not clear to you. You can edit it if you want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I re-read my answer and find out that the first sentences imply a relationship between immutability and the behavior described, and that is not correct as you pointed it out. That could be a factor if variables were being assigned values using as a right side other variables instead of object literals. I was just thinking about those cases even I did not put examples related to them. Thanks for your comments that make improve my answer. BTW, I learn details about the caching of the objects by CPython , I did not knew that was so limited.

Comment: @gsi-frank yes, Python is fundamentally much too dynamic to allow for true optimizations from immutability that you might see in a statically typed, functional programming language. The interpreter does special case `int` and actually `str` with string-interning. Other Python built-in containers have lots of optimizations for literals, too. The rules for string-interning are rather arcane, though.